# Should we still care about ajax-crawling specification?

Tags: ajax, seo, web-crawlers, single-page-application, googlebot

It seems [google crawlers run js](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more). But [documentations of ajax-crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) techniques are still available on Google Developers site.

Are they still valid and necessary to be followed?

Answer (score 1):

Both pages show that these pages are deprecated as of October 2015. Perhaps you're looking at a cached version of the page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google have in fact deprecated the AJAX crawling scheme.

They have a post on the Webmaster Central Blog [explaining this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html). Basically, if your site already uses it you'll continue being indexed as you already are. But as you upgrade your site you should move away from using the `_escaped_fragment_` technique.

Google now recommend using [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) techniques instead.