# Should "Rooms", "News", "Prices", etc be inside the "Hotel" Schema, or in another namespace?

Tags: seo, schema.org

I want to mark up a small hotel website using Schema.org. I wrapped the main page in

```
<div itemscope itemtype = "http://schema.org/Hotel">
</div>
```

Internal tags, such as address, name, etc., are also tagged (`itemprop = ""`). I need the search engine to create "quick links" for sections of the site (that is, additional columns in the search results). The documentation says that quick links are created by the search engine itself, provided that the sections of the site are correctly designed using markup.

How should other sections of the site be marked up?
For example, the sections "Rooms", "News", "Prices", etc.
Do they also need to be wrapped in **http://schema.org/Hotel**, or that should be another namespace?

Comment: As far as "quick links" go, I what you are talking about are usually called "site links".  They are not powered by Schema.  See [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: Google no longer supports `<meta name = "fragment" content = "!">` along with `?_escaped_fragment_=`.  That is called "AJAX Crawling" and Google deprecated it a while ago and recently stopped crawling it.   See  [Should we still care about ajax-crawling specification?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87519/should-we-still-care-about-ajax-crawling-specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should other sections of the site be marked up? For example, the sections "Rooms", "News", "Prices", etc. Do they also need to be wrapped in http://schema.org/Hotel, or that should be another namespace?

It depends on the kind of the information published in the certain section:

- If these are `Rooms` - its about `Hotel`
- If its about `Prices` - it should be filed under `Offer`
- If these are `News` - file it under `Hotel → mainEntityOfSite → Website → NewsArticle`